# What to put under Source Control in a Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, version-control, egit

I'm quite new to `Git (Svn)` and Java.

I want to put my `Java Project` (eventually a `Java Web project`) into source control, but I guess that some files doesn't have to be commited like `.class files` & `web.xml` for example.

So, what are files to commit (Servlets & JSPs), and how do I do to ignore other files, in an eclipse project? Do I need to use `.gitignore` file?

Comment: `web.xml` should be committed since it holds your application configuration. If you have two configurations, one for production and one for development, you should pass around both versions and have your build system decide which to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's something like a typical maven structure, this is how we do it:

1) cd $PROJECT
2) git init
3) git add pom.xml
4) git add src
5) echo 'target' > .gitignore
6) git commit -m "First commit"

Comment: To be fair, you could do this with Gradle or Ant. What makes Maven so great is how intuitive its convention over configuration approach is and how well it manages dependencies.

Comment: The question that I'm asking myself is do I have to follow all these steps when I use `Eclipse` with `EGit` plugin? or does it handle it by itself?

Comment: I use Netbeans and command line Git, but if you have at least run git init you should be able to have any Git plugin worth its salt able to handle it from there within the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Source control is/should be used to put the source and resources files in it. You should avoid putting the .class or any project settings file in source control. Class files are generated as per the latest source, you should put the build file in source control to help with that. Any project/environment related settings should not be pushed to source control as each person using that source may have different environment settings.

web.xml is a resource file and should be put in source control. All other resources such as config files can also go in your repository.

Comment: You mean by build file `build.xml`?

Comment: @h4k1m Yes it may build.xml or pom.xml depending which build tool you are using.

Comment: I'm using eclipse to code. How do I exclude the files which I don't wish to commit? Should I use `.gitignore` file?

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good project on GitHub: a collection of useful .gitignore templates:

https://github.com/github/gitignore